# dynamic WPF ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have WPF and dynamic contextMenu. I have  menuitem1.click and menuitem2.click.

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mItem1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem1" };
mItem1.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mItem1_Click);
MenuItem mItem2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem2" };
mItem2.Click += new ystem.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mItem2_Click);
```

Now when i call

```
 private void mItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    //need to put mItem1.enabled=false and mItem2.Enabled = false    

 }
```

How do i do this? do I use contextMenu.Items something and what?
           `

Comment: Cast sender to MenuItem and set it's Enabled property. ((MenuItem)sender).Enabled = ..

Comment: what about other menuitem?

Comment: Then go even deeper and access item's parent and cast it to ContextMenu: (ContextMenu) ((MenuItem) sender).Parent. There you will have a collection of Items, which will contain both items. Btw, I don't recommend such approach, but technically it would work. A better approach would be using MVVM, bindings and ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the `MenuItem` objects dynamically, you could just keep a reference to them using two private fields. Then you can access them directly in the event handlers:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MenuItem mItem1;
    MenuItem mItem2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        mItem1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem1" };
        mItem1.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mItem1_Click);
        mItem2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem2" };
        mItem2.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mItem2_Click);
    }

    private void mItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mItem1.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void mItem2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Another option may be to use anonymous methods:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mItem1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem1" };
MenuItem mItem2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "mItem2" };
mItem1.Click += (ss, ee) => 
{
    mItem2.IsEnabled = false;
};
mItem2.Click += (ss, ee) => 
{

};
```

Comment: it would have been easy if the two menuitems are global and i have much more code for the click events

Comment: It is just a matter of defining two fields in the same class where the event handlers are defined. What is the problem...?